# loadRawData Memory issue in ogre while load opencv frames

Tags: c++, opencv, ogre3d, ogre

I am capturing images in real time using OpenCV, and I want to show these images in the OGRE window as a background. So, for each frame the background will change.

I am trying to use `MemoryDataStream` along with `loadRawData` to load the images into an OGRE window, but I am getting the following error:

> OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Stream size does not
>   match calculated image size in Image::loadRawData at
>   ../../../../../OgreMain/src/OgreImage.cpp (line 283)

An image comes from OpenCV with a size of 640x480 and `frame->buffer` is a type of `Mat` in OpenCV 2.3. Also, the pixel format that I used in OpenCV is `CV_8UC3` (i.e., each pixel is 8-bits and each pixel contains 3 channels ( B8G8R8 ) ).

```
Ogre::MemoryDataStream* videoStream = new Ogre::MemoryDataStream((void*)frame->buffer.data, 640*480*3, true);
Ogre::DataStreamPtr ptr(videoStream,Ogre::SPFM_DELETE);
ptr->seek(0);
Ogre::Image* image =  new Ogre::Image();
image->loadRawData(ptr,640, 480,Ogre::PF_B8G8R8 );
texture->unload();
texture->loadImage(*image)
```

Why I always getting this memory error?

Answer (score 1):

Quick idea, maybe memory 4-byte alignment issues ?

see [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712899/what-is-the-memory-structure-of-opencvs-cvmat) and 
[Link 2](http://chi3x10.wordpress.com/2008/05/07/be-aware-of-memory-alignment-of-iplimage-in-opencv/)

Comment: I tried 4 byte alignment but nothing didnt change. I always get a same memory problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Ogre expert, but does it work if you use [loadDynamicImage](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1Image.html#a5216235925e6373c0f5083da1e079c1a) instead?

**EDIT :** Just for grins try using the `Mat` fields to setup the buffer:

```
Ogre::Image* image = new Ogre::Image();
image->loadDynamicImage((uchar*)frame->buffer.data, frame->buffer.cols, frame->buffer.rows, frame->buffer.channels(), Ogre::PF_B8G8R8);
```

This will avoid copying the image data, and should let the `Mat` delete it's contents later.

Comment: It doesnt work,  I try. My problem is more about an inequality between image size and buffer size

Comment: And, you're sure the frame size is 640x480x3?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems to get image data into OGRE, in my case the data came from ROS (see ros.org). The thing is that your data in frame->buffer is not RAW, but has a file header etc.
I think my solution was to search the data stream for the beginning of the image (by finding the appropriate indicator in the data block, e.g. 0x4D 0x00), and inserting the data from this point on.

You would have to find out were in your buffer the header ends and where your data begins.