# IplImage vs CvMat

Tags: c++, c, opencv, matrix, iplimage

I know many people are interested in the **technical difference** between `IplImage` and `CvMat`. (Yes, NOT `cv::Mat`(*), but `CvMat`.) So, let's clear the differences with a practical focus.

Is `CvMat` the refcounted version of `IplImage`? Is `CvMat` only a wrapper around `IplImage`? If so, why did they also develop `CvMat`?

I asked these questions because **I saw `IplImage` being [far and away the most popular](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=IplImage%2C%20cv%3A%3AMat%2C%20cvMat&cmpt=q)** at the overall searches and in my opinion it also has the most posts.

**What is the benefit of still using IplImage** instead of newer structures?

(*)(I have put also c++ tag here as many people are using it also with c++, and also some libraries prefer `IplImage`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IplImage` came from the Intel Image Processing library, according to the docs: 
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#iplimage

This question also addresses the `CvMat` structure, which may be of note to you:
[What is the memory structure of OpenCV's cvMat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712899/what-is-the-memory-structure-of-opencvs-cvmat)

As regards which is more beneficial: while there may be slight speed differences here or there with either `CvMat` or `IplImage` in various contexts — it depends on what you want to do. E.g. do you need to share a matrix structure in memory? Do you need to efficiently serialize, or search, etc? The application matters.

(Theoretically, one advantage offered by `IplImage` is that due to its pedigree, it's generally more compatible with existing implementations, as you noted.)

Comment: I meant "share in memory" as in, "dynamically reuse allocated memory in-place as some other struct" which wasn't super-clear from my comment (my apologies) ... e.g. similar how you can simply `memcpy()`  CImg instances directly for use as `IplImage` instances (see https://github.com/fish2000/cython-imaging/blob/master/CIL/ext/include/CImg/plugins/cimg_ipl.h#L278) if their color channels are in the right order. Depending on your needs, the `IplImage` struct may or may not help you in this case.

Comment: ... incedentally I actually have no idea if there is a refcounting scheme in play for either structure (although I doubt it), offhand.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to read paragraph **OpenCV Primitive Data Types** from the book [Learning OpenCV](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/vision/dipakmj/papers/OReilly%20Learning%20OpenCV.pdf). There's a big and good explanation about difference between these two datatypes.

Comment: thanks! I don't know how I could forget looking at that part, +1.

Answer (score 3):

Answering your question:

> What is the benefit of still using IplImage instead of newer
>   structures?

Maybe none. It has been deprecated by the devs for some reason, I would guess that the reason why you still find it a lot is because of legacy code; because people still follow old code samples not being aware that the structure is deprecated and because "Learning OpenCV **first edition**" is outdated with regards to the opencv functions signatures and data structures but it is still followed by a lot of people starting with opencv.

As a reference, [Learning OpenCV 2nd edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022497.do) is supposed to be out March 2013, but don't quote me on that ;)

Comment: When I started to experiment with the "deprecated" IplImage (instead of cv::Mat), some functionalities were surprisingly well written there and I had more firm control over the memory. I felt like I could better reuse my memory allocations. (For some reason cv::Mat's leak on Mac whereas IplImage's don't.)